# How does one use @e data on a custom named snowball

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The below command does not work on a Snowball and I was wondering how to do it.

`execute @e[name=snowy] ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.1 5`

Answer (score 1):

In order for your command to work, you either have to first actually assign the name "snowy" to the snowballs, or simply work directly with the snowballs.

The former can be achieved by running the following command on the same clock as the your execute command:

```
entitydata @e[type=Snowball] {CustomName:"snowy"}
```

Note how this command simply affects all snowballs even though they are not named yet? We can cut out the middle man by simply using

```
execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.1 5
```

The Minecraft wiki has a list of all valid [target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments), and the valid Entity IDs for the `type` selector are found in sidebars alongside the [NBT data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format).